# Irreducibility of $(ρ,V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $g$ be a semisimple Lie algebra, and $(ρ,V)$ a finite-dimensional representation of $g.$ We can see that the irreducibility of $(ρ,V)$ implies that $End_{g}(V) = \{kI_n : k \in $C$\}.$ This is due to Schur's lemma, and the semi-simpleness of $g$ is not required. Can you help me to prove the converse part using the semi-simpleness of $g$?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: What converse do you mean? That if $\text{End}(V) \cong \mathbb{C}$ then the representation is simple? Prove the contrapositive: if the representation isn't simple it must have a larger endomorphism ring.

Comment: Yes, I meant what you've mentioned as the converse. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a bit why "it must have a larger endomorphism ring?"

Comment: Try to prove it! Use semisimplicity!

Comment: Thanks so much. I proved it finally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $V = \bigoplus V_i$ with simple representations $V_i$, what is $\mathrm{End}_g(V) = \mathrm{Hom}_g(\bigoplus V_i, \bigoplus V_i$)? Use finite additivity of Hom, and Schur's Lemma.

---

As an example of why one needs semisimplicity, look at the Lie algebra $g:= \{\pmatrix{a&b\\0&0}: a,b \in \mathbb C\}$ and its natural representation on $V= \mathbb C^2$. Show that $\mathrm{End}_g(V) \simeq \mathbb C$ but $V$ has a proper subrepresentation. Compare with the above to see what exactly semisimplicity is needed for.

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact, I did the exact same thing. Now, I feel confident about my argument. Thanks again.